# systemd: automate modprobe command at boot time

Tags: systemd, kernel-modules, startup, modprobe

My distribution is Fedora 17 Gnome.
Every time I reboot/restart my computer I need to run this command as root:

```
modprobe rt2800usb
```

How can I make it permanent?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you first question. It would be nice if you could mention which linux distribution you're referring to :)

Comment: @BonsiScott The distribution should probably be added to the question text, as well, but the tag says Fedora.

Comment: (Also, deleted my own answer because it is not fedora-specific)

Comment: @BonsiScott, your answer could well be useful for others...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

On any distro using `systemd` you can automatically load the module via [`modules-load.d`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/modules-load.d.html):

- create the config file:

  `/etc/modules-load.d/rt2800usb.conf`
- open it and edit like this (add the module name):

  `rt2800usb`
- next time you reboot the module should be automatically loaded

---

Troubleshooting:

Check if `systemd` service loaded the module:

```sh
systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
```

The output should look like this:

```sh
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
  Active: active (exited) since Wed, 03 Apr 2013 22:50:57 +0000; 46s ago
        Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
              man:modules-load.d(5)
 Process: 260 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

The last line contains the `PID` (process id) and the exit code. `status=0/SUCCESS` means the module was successfully inserted, confirmed by:

```sh
journalctl -b _PID=260
```

output being:

```sh
Apr 03 22:50:57 mxhst systemd-modules-load[260]: Inserted module 'rt2800usb'
```

In case of failure, `systemctl` output looks like this:

```sh
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed, 03 Apr 2013 22:50:59 +0000; 43s ago
        Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
              man:modules-load.d(5)
 Process: 260 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

with `journalctl -b` reporting:

```sh
Apr 03 22:50:59 mxhst systemd-modules-load[260]: Failed to find module 'fakert2800usb'
```

When the exit code is `0/SUCCESS` it means your module has been successfully inserted; running

```
lsmod | grep rt2800
```

should confirm that:

```
rt2800usb              26854  0 
rt2x00usb              19757  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              64762  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              66520  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              578735  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
```

If `lsmod` output doesn't confirm (despite the service exit code being `0/SUCCESS`) it means something removed the module after being loaded by `modules-load.service`. One possible cause is another `*.conf` file that blacklisted the module. Look for a line like:

```
blacklist rt2800usb
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf`, `/usr/lib/modprobe.d/*.conf` or `/run/modprobe.d/*.conf` and comment it out / delete it.

Comment: I've done this, but the module didn't load on reboot.

Comment: Is it because root is the owner of the file?

Comment: When I reboot, I still have to do the modprbe command. Isn't it listed because the listing is after I ran the modprobe command?

Comment: If you need persisting module parameters: `options <module_name> [parameter=value]` on `/etc/modprobe.d/[filename].conf` (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-Loading_a_Customized_Module-Persistent_Changes)

Answer (score 9):

To load a module on boot, you create a file in `/etc/modules-load.d/`; this file can have any name, but must end in `.conf`. In the case of your wifi driver, you could for example create the file `/etc/modules-load.d/rt2800.conf`.

In the file, add a single line with the name of the module you want to load like so:

```
rt2800usb
```

The Arch Wiki page on [Kernel modules](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Loading) has more information.